# CSS font including not shown in browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm linking a CSS file in HTML. The CSS file is uploaded on another server and the CSS file import fonts from the same place and the path is correct, but gives an error and doesn't work.

Here are the screenshots: https://pasteboard.co/Ig0ORen.jpg

This the font error: https://pasteboard.co/Ig0KwNlP.jpg

It is was working when the CSS was on my localhost but I want to upload the CSS and JS and fonts in this server.

This is the HTML code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/lib/styles/process.css">
```

This is the CSS codeL

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: pp-sans-small-light;
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_light.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_light.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/p_small_light.woff) format("woff"), url(../fonts/p_small_light.svg) format("svg")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: pp-sans-small-regular;
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_regular.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_regular.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/p_small_regular.woff) format("woff"), url(../fonts/p_small_regular.svg) format("svg")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'consumer-icons';
    src: url(../fonts/icons_sans.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/icons_sans.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(../fonts/icons_sans.woff) format('woff'), url(../fonts/icons_sans.ttf) format('truetype'), url(../fonts/icons_sans.svg) format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400
}

@font-face {
    font-family: p_big_sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url(../fonts/p_big_sans.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/p_big_sans.woff2) format('woff2'), url(../fonts/p_big_sans.woff) format('woff'), url(../fonts/p_big_sans.svg) format('svg')
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
        font-family: pp-sans-small-regular, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Try going to your css file directly in the browser. You should see it as text on your screen. Your screen shots don't show any information about whether the browser successfully found it. Use the developer tools of the browser to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Check permission in your server for those font files which are not getting loaded. I have attached screenshot for you reference. Right click on files & folder and change permission to 755.

[image]

Comment: are you can give me more details about [How to make / check that ?]
Iam use Hostinger Host

Comment: Please MR @Yashwant Munda can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have only referenced the @font-face fonts here -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: pp-sans-small-light;
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_light.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_light.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url(../fonts/p_small_light.woff) format("woff"), url(../fonts/p_small_light.svg) 
    format("svg")
}
```

..but you haven't declared their use anywhere.

You need to assign the fonts where you want to use them, for example;

```
body { font-family: pp-sans-small-regular; }
p { font-family: pp-sans-small-light; }
```

Comment: it is already declared
'body {
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: pp-sans-small-regular, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif
}'

Comment: @SH3NZ0 - That code should really have been part of your question.

Comment: Ok, one other thing, do you have the full URL for the fonts you're calling?  As the URL you've specified for them suggests the font is being stored locally, which doesn't seem right to me for web fonts.